# Crazy data being returned by EF4 - wrong data & even wrong columns

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a core set of code that I have been using for ages to create websites with and it uses EF4 and hooks through to SQL Server 2008 R2 ...   all has been working fine on mostly low level sites until yesterday when a site started to bomb all over the place.  When we traced the errors we found that data returned from Linq to entities was just bizarre ?

We have seen,  different rows returning the same data,   repeated reports of wrong data types,  the Id column got returned instead of the value from the column we were querying.and when we check to see if a count tells us we have rows for a loop ...the count says 1 row found, then when we loop we get a null reference.

Does Anybody know what's happening here ?   It's freaking me out.

Comment: Where's this happen?  Can you duplicate it on another system?  Is the data in the DB good?  Any library changes?

Comment: The Data in the DB is fine, I can query it Directly in management studio and its fine ....  and this problem is intermittent ...  so,etimes the data is ok .. sometimes not.

Comment: I should point out its LINQ to EF4 to SQL2008_R2 on a 1and1 Cloud server ...   it seems to get worse as loading increases but there are no database errors or connecction errors and its really not _THAT_ loaded ...

Comment: Also the main data that is coming back wrong is a table called 'settings' and the rows we are calling are never really updated (the table itself is often) ...

Comment: Are you sure the database isn't corrupt? I once had a database with corrupted indexes which raied similar symptoms. Try [DBCC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue this morning. The relevant data was accurate, and the returned entity count was correct. However, the property values of the entities were wrong. The main problem that I saw was that sets of values that should have been used for only a single entity were used for multiple entities. Long story short, the composite key wasn't appropriate because it only specified 2 of the 3 values that formed the key. I added the final key to the configuration and the correct values were returned.